# Highcharts multiple yaxis plotband collision

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have been trying using angular gauge with multiple y axis. I have used offset axis property to avoid collision between them. However, plotband of the axes getting collided with each other. Is there any property to separate them out or any other workaround?

My try:

```
$(function () {

    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'gauge',
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBackgroundImage: null,
            plotBorderWidth: 0,
            plotShadow: false
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Speedometer'
        },

        pane: {
            startAngle: -90,
            endAngle: 90,
            background: null
        },

        // the value axis
        yAxis:[
        {
            min: 0,
            max:100,

            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 1,
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#666',
                  labels: {
                distance: 12,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            offset: -30,
            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 2,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#666',
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },

             plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 10,
                color: '#55BF3B',
            }, {
                from: 10,
                to: 70,
                color: '#DDDF0D',
            }, {
                from: 70,
                to: 90,
                color: '#DF5353',  
            }]


        },
         {
            min: 0,
            max:100,

            minorTickInterval: 'auto',
            minorTickWidth: 1,
            minorTickLength: 10,
            minorTickPosition: 'inside',
            minorTickColor: '#666',
                  labels: {
                distance: 12,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },
            offset: 30,
            tickPixelInterval: 30,
            tickWidth: 2,
            tickPosition: 'inside',
            tickLength: 10,
            tickColor: '#666',
            labels: {
                step: 2,
                rotation: 'auto'
            },

             plotBands: [{
                from: 0,
                to: 10,
                color: 'red',
                offset:30,// green
            }, {
                from: 10,
                to: 70,
                color: 'orange' // yellow
            }, {
                from: 70,
                to: 90,
                color: 'violet' // red
            }]


        }

        ],

        series: [{
            name: 'Speed',
             data: [{
                id: 'hour',
                y: 90,
            }],
        },{
        name: 'Speed',
             data: [{
                id: 'minute',
                y: 50,
            }],
        },
        ]

    },



    // Add some life
    function (chart) {
        if (!chart.renderer.forExport) {
            setInterval(function () {

            }, 3000);
        }
    });

        $('.highcharts-axis text').click(function(){                                      alert($(this).text());  
        }); 
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/n1djkxLr/8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is related with know bug, reported to our developers here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/5283